# Postgres operator not working in Rails app with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my Rails app I'm trying to get an array of records from Postgres then show them in the app. One looks like this:

```
<% featured = Product.order('RANDOM()').limit(3).where.not(photo_file_name: nil, sold_value: true) %>
```

This works fine, but another in another instance it doesn't. Here:

```
<% recentlistings = Product.order('created_at DESC').limit(3).where.not(user_id: current_user.id, photo_file_name: nil, sold_value: true) %>
```

If I remove the `photo_file_name` operator it works fine. Any reason why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the second query just returning orders with no photo file name (when you remove it)?

The first query doesn't seem to incorporate the (not) current user criterion...

In other words, is this simply a matter of different queries producing different results?

You might look at your log file (or console output if you're running locally) to see what queries are actually being generated. (You could always post that here, too.)

Comment: Silly mistake, it was due to the not current user criterion in dev mode